# Find $\int{x^2chxdx}$ where $chx$ is hyperbolic cosine.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

Find $\int{x^2chxdx}$ where $chx$ is hyperbolic cosine.

My steps.

$\int x^2chxdx$ = $x^2shx-\int{shxdx^2} = x^2shx-\int{shx2xdx}= x^2shx-2\int{xshxdx}$

I can't continue from here.How find $\int xshxdx$

Comment: Use \sinh and \cosh to get the correct formatting. You're on the right track; you did integration by parts once. Do it again to simplify $\int x\sinh x\,dx$

Answer (score 1):

Integrate by parts again. We have

$$\int x^2\cosh(x)dx=x^2\sinh(x)-2\int x\sinh(x)dx$$
$$=x^2\sinh(x)-2\left[x\cosh(x)-\int\cosh(x)dx\right]$$
$$=x^2\sinh(x)-2x\cosh(x)+2\sinh(x)+C$$

Comment: Shouldn't there be $\int cosh(x)d\frac{x^2}{2}$?

Comment: No, it's correct how I've written it. It's the same [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) method. You can take  $u(x)=\cosh(x)$ and $v'(x)=x^2$.